# How to whitelist MongoProperties in custom processor application?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have written a custom processor app to read data from MongoDB. In this app, I use **MongoTemplate** for MongoDB operation, so SpringBoot has provide the **MongoProperties** class for properties loading.

However, when I try to white list MongoProperties so that I can see these properties on WebUI dashboard, I encounter some problem. It just shows **"No properties avaliable"**.

I have followed the [23.1 Whitelisting application properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-whitelisting) in the document to add the following line in **spring-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties** file

```
configuration-properties.classes=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoProperties
```

And add the following dependency in **pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

I have read the code of [spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/mongodb](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/mongodb)
 on github. It seems that it does the same with me.

Actually, I have written several other apps, and the WebUI shows the white-listed properties normally. The only difference is that, in these apps, I create my own **@ConfigurationProperty** class.

May I ask, what else should I do to white list the spring boot provided **@ConfigurationProperty** class(in my case, MongoProperties)?

Thank you very much for any advice!

Comment: finally, it turned out to be SCDF version issue. This problem appeared on SCDF on YARN 1.0.2.RELEASE and disappeared on SCDF Local 1.1.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to debug this is to unpack your application jar file and verify if you have :

`META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties
META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json`

in your classpath (usually via app starter jar) and the `spring-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties` has the entries for the required properties

Comment: thanks, Ilayaperumal, I have the META-INF/*.properties file but do not have the META-INF/*.json file

Comment: I have done further test by add a self-defined **@ConfigurationProperty** class, and **META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json** is generated. It seems that `spring-boot-configuration-processor` only generate meta data for self defined @ConfigurationProperty class but not for that in dependency library

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the `.json` file is directly in your uber-jar, or embedded in a (boot provided) jar that itself is in your uber-jar. If you can confirm that indeed this is the case, then your problem comes from something else (typo in class name?, in key name?, in file name?). If the sources of your app are publicly available, then please point to them we may be able to reproduce

Comment: @ebottard Thanks for your advice. I have double checked the file name, key name and class name(actually, I copied the config file from another project). The source is available at [scdf-read-mongo-processor](https://github.com/javyzheng/scdf-read-mongo-processor) and I will appreciate it if you could give more advice on the usage. My SCDF server   is 1.0.2.RELEASE on YARN

Comment: I tried it (with current version) and it worked like a charm. Could you try with a newer version of SCDF? There were changes related to supporting boot 1.4+ in SCDF 1.1.x

Comment: @ebottard Thank you very much! It may be related to SCDF version. I think I have to study the possibility of reinstalling SCDF server. Thanks again!

Comment: I also tried it with SCDF local server 1.1.3.RELEASE, and it worked, so I can confirm now this is a version problem. Thank your both for the help!